# Merge a Php array into a Php object

Tags: php, json, type-conversion

I need to merge a php array INTO a php object.

I need my php object to look like this :

```
{"info1":"value","concurrents":[{"concurrent1":"value"},{"concurent2":"value"}],"info3":"value"};
```

, I'm actually getting my initial object like this :

```
$initial = pg_fetch_object($result);
```

After that, I'm getting the array with this command :

```
$concurrents = pg_fetch_all($result);
```

So please, how could i merge $concurrents INSIDE my $initial object, for executing  this finally for destination to the front end:

```
print_r(json_encode($initial));
```

I've tried a `foreach`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That's nice, but what are you fetching? What have you tried?

Comment: Show `$initial` and `$concurrents`.

Comment: I'm fetching sql data with postgre... I wanna return my JSON object to angularJs, it works very well except that i need to include this array inside my JSON OBJECT, its regular json it works except that i dont know how to generate it with php back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
$initial->concurrents = $concurrents;
```

Or even:

```
$initial->concurrents = pg_fetch_all($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get your initial result as an object, get it as an array:

```
$initial = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then 'merging' is fairly easy (push the initial on to the beginning of your `concurrents` array):

```
$concurrents = pg_fetch_all($result);
array_unshift($concurrents, $initial);
```

Now you can print them:

```
print_r(json_encode($concurrents));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot But Will it print an array ? Because the front end angularjs need an Object, not an array., in this particular case, thank a lot for your answer.